# php mail() script not working

Tags: php, forms, sendmail

Hey guys I cannot for the life of me figure out where I went wrong here. When the form submits it takes it to a blank page. No errors or confirmed. Just Blank. Im assuming it is a syntax error but I just cant see it for some reason. Do you guys see anything?
Here is my form code:

```
<form method="POST" action="mailtest.php">

<label>Name<span class="req">*</span></label>
<input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

<label>Email<span class="req">*</span></label>
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

<label>Subject</label>
<input name="subjectf" placeholder="Type Here">

<label>Message<span class="req">*</span></label>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

<input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="">
<span class="right" style="color:red">* represents a mandatory field.</span>
</form>
```

And here is the php script I have on the mailtest.php page:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = $_POST['name'];
    $to = 'rkoolman@bellsouth.net'; 
    $subject= 'new enquiry on website';
    $subjectf= $_POST['subjectf'];  
    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Subject: $subjectf\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $message != '') {         
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } 
    } else {
        echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: isset($_POST['submit'])
may help :)

Comment: Mail is a tricky thing to debug, are you getting any error messages at all?

Comment: no error messages at all. Just a blank page. I just tryed the "isset($_POST['submit'])" and it gives me this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/a2375440/public_html/mailtest.php on line 11Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/a2375440/public_html/mailtest.php on line 11". Line 11 being the line that I just inserted that on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always first check whether the form was submitted so

remove `if ($_POST['submit'])` and put it on the top of the script..

also you should check whther the `$_POST["submit"]` was set.. the script should look like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = $_POST['name'];
    $to = 'test@test.com'; 
    $subject= 'new enquiry on website';
    $subjectf= $_POST['subjectf'];  
    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Subject: $subjectf\n Message:\n $message";


    if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $message != '') {         
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } 
    } else {
        echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! I got a "Your message has been sent!" But I just checked my email/spam and it is not there. Are there other settings I have to change in the php.ini or somthing?

Comment: you will need smtp mail server to send mails.. and uncheck the smtp and port 25 option in your phpini..

Comment: when more problems arise, i suggest turn to PHPMailer and throw mail() outta window, fast!

Answer (score 0):

Set your submit input value to submit

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```