# PHP script not working. Receiving error 404. Web server DOES support PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following form and php script:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <h1>Contact</h1> 

    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

    <input id="submit" class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'SJW&T Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'someone@example.com'; 
    $subject = 'Hello';
    $human = $_POST['human'];

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {              
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
        } 
    }
?>
```

But my web host seems to be returning an error 404. I tried the suggestion in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329398/php-mail-script-not-working), which is a near duplicate, but it did not work. Anyone see any syntax errors? My web host is 000webhost.com. It doesn't give me an actual 404 message, but the URL it takes me to is error404.000webhost.com.

Comment: A syntax error would not cause a 404 error. Something else must be the problem.

Comment: Maby you could try the PHPSELF as action ,http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html

Comment: I don't feel this post gives the correct information to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded your file to the correct location?

Comment: What information is needed to help fix this problem? Is it just a problem with my host? If so, I suppose I'll just delete the question.

Comment: @jeroen There are no additional files. It's just an index.html file with some embedded php.

Comment: @ByronS So you see the form? If so, change the filename to `index.php` instead of `index.html`. That way your `action` is valid and the php will be processed.

Comment: Crappy tutorial by the way, you should move your assignments to inside the `if` statement and use `isset()` or `empty()` to get rid of the warnings.

Comment: Expanding on @jeroen's comment, if a file has the `html` extension, the web server will not parse any PHP, as it interprets the page as an HTML file.  Changing the extension to `php` will tell the web server "hey, I'm a PHP file. Parse anything between `<?php` and `?>` as PHP".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might happen, when you don't have the action page:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
```

You set the action page to **index.php**, so if that file doesn't exist or located somewhere else,
you might get a 404 error or Object not found.

Make sure you have index.php AND it exists in the same directory with your other files.

If you want to take the action on the page itself, then do:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

Comment: The tutorial I am following asked me to place the php script directly under the form so that it's output would appear there. Do I have to make another file as well?

Comment: Well, of course, you set the action page to index.php, if you wanted the action to the page itself then you would do this: `<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form action name is the same thing as the file name. E.g form action-"forms.php".      make sure the folder or file name is also-forms.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

< print >

- $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

I think this will solve ur problem.